# How to manage HTTP Request from a Silex API REST

Tags: php, rest, api, silex

I'll start this topic with apologies for all mistakes I'll do. I'm French and this is obviously not my mother tongue.If you are French, I invite you to respond me in french.

I'm an internship student, I have to create an API REST. I'm using Silex PHP Frameworks to help me. I'm gonna explain my problem:

I created a connexion system in PHP that ask your login and your password. Those informations are going to the API by the action of the HTML form:

When the api get informations, it will test those informations with informations stocked in database. If an account are similar, it will send an HTTP code: 201 because everything will be OK. Else, it will send a 401 (Identification issue).

But this HTTP code is send to `API.php/api/connexion` not to my `connexion.php`! 
I wanna make a thing like: if the http code of connexion.php change to 201, make a redirection to accueil.php (home page in english) else if the code is 401, display an error message.

I hope your eyes ain't bleeding that much and I succeed to be explicit.

Have a nice day !

Comment: I'm afraid it's still difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve. You seem to be describing a standard web application, not a REST API. If I understand you correctly, you want the login endpoint to send a 302 redirect instead of a 201 Created (which, by the way, should be 200 OK) to the user, is this correct? If not, please try to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'll try to explain it by a little diagram:

(connexion.php) client enter login password --> (api.php/api/connexion) Api check if this account exist or not ---> send his HTTP 200 or 401 to connexion.php ---> connexion.php receive the HTTP code and then redirect to the home page if it's a sucessfull connexion or display an error message. 

My problem is "after checking if the account exist, how can I send the http code to connexion.php"

Comment: Mind sharing your controller code?